# Where is the gazebo_ros_api_plugin.cpp file located?

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've been trying to create my own subscribers/publishers with gazebo_ros and have had trouble finding this file: gazebo_ros_api_plugin.cpp. I'm assuming that this would be what I would need to modify in order to get the /gazebo node subscribing to new publishers and publishing to new subscribers. I have Ubuntu 12.04, Gazebo 1.9 (although that may have gotten updated to 3.0), ROS Hydro.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6949/where-is-the-gazebo_ros_api_plugin.cpp-file-located?/) by [nbanyk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/857/nbanyk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 104 on 2014-09-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nbanyk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/857/nbanyk/) on 2014-09-03**:
I should clarify that I tried using find and grep to find it and had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

it is in the [gazebo_ros package on github](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/hydro-devel/gazebo_ros/src/gazebo_ros_api_plugin.cpp)

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nbanyk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/857/nbanyk/) on 2014-09-03**:
Yes, but when you install it on a computer (from here http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_installing&cat=connect_ros), where does it get placed?

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2014-09-03**:
If you install from pre-built debians, then the source file won't be included. If you install from source according to the instructions, then it will be at `~/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros/src/gazebo_ros_api_plugin.cpp`

**Comment by [nbanyk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/857/nbanyk/) on 2014-09-04**:
perfect! thank you!